# SQL - Calculate next row based on previous in the same column

Tags: sql

I have spent hours trying to solve this with loops, the lag function but it doesn't solve my problem. I have a table where the first row of a particular field is populated, the next row is calculated based on a subtraction of the previous row of data from 2 columns, the next row is then based on the result of this. The example is below of the original table and the result set:

```
   a      b         a       b   
 502.5  33.85     502.5   33.85 
        25.46     468.65  25.46 
        20.83     443.19  20.83 
        133.07    422.36  133.07
        144.65    289.29  144.65
        144.65    144.64  144.65
```

I have tried several different methods with stored procedures and can get the 2nd row result set but I can't get it to continue and calculate the rest of the fields, it's easy in excel but not so in SQL. Any suggestions?

Comment: Use the `lag()` function

Answer (score 0):

If your RDBMS supports windowed aggregate functions:

Assuming you have an `id` or some such thing that is determining the order of your rows (as you indicated there is a first).

You can use the `max() over()` (in this case `min()` works instead of `max()` as well) and `sum() over()` windowed aggregate functions

```
select 
    id 
  , max(a) over (order by id) - (sum(b) over (order by id) - b) as a
  , b
from t
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/MGKM17497

returns:

```
+----+--------+--------+
| id |   a    |   b    |
+----+--------+--------+
|  1 | 502,50 | 33,85  |
|  2 | 468,65 | 25,46  |
|  3 | 443,19 | 20,83  |
|  4 | 422,36 | 133,07 |
|  5 | 289,29 | 144,65 |
|  6 | 144,64 | 144,65 |
+----+--------+--------+
```

Comment: Fantastic that worked! And has allowed me to do calculations like that. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

In case, as I saw data before editing )

This solution also assumes that you have `id` column and order depends on this column

```
with t(id, a, b) as(
    select 1, 502.5,  33.85 union all
    select 2, 25.46,  null union all
    select 3, 20.83,  null union all
    select 4, 133.07, null union all
    select 5, 144.65, null union all
    select 6, 144.65, null  
)

select case when id = 1 then a else b end as a, case when id = 1 then (select b from t order by id offset 0 rows fetch next 1 rows only) else a end as b from (
    select id, a, lag((select a from t order by id offset 0 rows fetch next 1 rows only)-s) over(order by id) as b from (
        select id, a, sum(case when b is null then a else b end  ) over(order by id) s
        from t
    ) tt
) ttt
```