# How to implement different formulas into rows of the same SQL column

Tags: mysql, sql, javafx

I'm trying to perform Excel-like auto calculations where by each row of a specific column will have a different formula.

[image: image Before]
[image: image After].

Below is my attempt on it. My codes may not look professional because i'm still learning java. 
Please i need a help on this.

```
int row = 5;
for(int a=0; a< row; a++){  
  pst = con.prepareStatement("select "+category+"_medicationValue,"+category+"_feedingValue,"+category+"_rawmaterialValue from "+db+".forecast where Cycle="+a+" ");
  rs = pst.executeQuery();
  while (rs.next()) {

      double medication = rs.getDouble(category+"_medicationValue");
      double feeding = rs.getDouble(category+"_feedingValue");
      double rawMaterial = rs.getDouble(category+"_rawmaterialValue");



      double per90M = 0.0;
      double per90F = 0.0;
      double per90R = 0.0;

      for(int i=0; i< row; ++i){

           per90M = per90M + ((medication * 0.9) + medication);
           per90F = per90F + ((feeding * 0.9) + feeding);
           per90R = per90R + ((rawMaterial * 0.9) + rawMaterial);

      Alert alert2 = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
      alert2.setTitle("Success");
      alert2.setHeaderText("Forecast");
      alert2.setContentText("med: "+per90M+"Feed :"+per90F+"raw M: "+per90R);
      alert2.showAndWait();

      pst = con.prepareStatement("update "+db+".forecast set "+category+"_medicationValue=?,"+category+"_feedingValue=?,"+category+"_rawmaterialValue=? where Cycle="+i+" ");

          pst.setDouble(1, per90M);
          pst.setDouble(2, per90F);
          pst.setDouble(3, per90R);

          pst.executeUpdate();
      }}

  }
  Alert alert1 = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
      alert1.setTitle("Success");
      alert1.setHeaderText("Forecast");
      alert1.setContentText(category+" details has been linearlly forecasted");
      alert1.showAndWait();
  }
  pst.close();
  rs.close();
```

Comment: Are the real calculations very time-consuming? I'm not sure I understand why you would ever do this otherwise. There's not much point in persisting something to a database when you can readily calculate it on-the-fly anyway.

Comment: @James_D the calculation isn't time consuming. I'm only trying to perform excel-like calculation on Java where each row in same column would have same formula but different variable such that the answer of the first row becomes the variable input of the second row and so on...I really need to implement this to achieve my forecast pattern. Thanks for your reply anyway.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I'm just not understanding. I get the relationships among the data, but I don't understand why you want to store the results of the calculation in a database.

Comment: @James_D The data will be beneficial for reference sake (e.g. charts). If there is an alternative I'll be happy to hear it from you. Thanks.

Comment: A similar question was asked by L Rome. The link to the question is attached below https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43694929/sql-calculate-next-row-based-on-previous-in-the-same-column. The difference here is that it's a single column only populated by the first row. The result of the first row is used as the input of the second row and so on. I hope this link will bring an understanding of my previous posts. thanks.